# Can I create my own component tag?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to make original preset of lightning component.

For example,

`<mycomponent:ButtonandTable>`, which makes lightning:button and lightning:datatable just as it was described.

My component has so many elements, so i want to put together tags and create my own tag.

Does salesforce have any method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an aura component englobing those 2 components

myCustomComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:attribute name="buttonLabel" type="string" />
  <aura:attribute name="tableData" type="Object" />
  <aura:attribute name="onButtonClick" type="Aura.Action" description="JS controller action to perform when button pressed"/>

  <lightning:button label="{!v.buttonLabel}" onclick="{!v.onButtonClick}" />
  <lightning:datatable data="{!v.tableData}" />

</aura:component>
```

Then call it from anywhere

```
<c:myCustomComponent buttonLabel="MyButtonLabel" tableTable="{}" onButtonClick="{!c.handleCustomCmpClick}" />
```

Controller:

```
handleCustomCmpClick(component,event,helper) {
    console.log('Button clicked !');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can it have own method like onclick or  onchange?

Comment: Edited my answer for your case :) Plz mark it as the good answer if it fits your requirements :)